# Cocoa/OSX tagging UI

Tags: cocoa, macos, tags, tagging

I'm looking to implement a tagging interface on OSX that lets users type text "tags" to attach to an object. Ideally, I'd like to implement a fancy UI like the screenshot below:

[image] 
    -

```
Note: This shows multiple states
```

This UI lets the user type tags, then groups them into a rounded shape when enter is pressed. They can be deleted by dragging over to highlight (shown in dark blue) and pressing delete. I think this is a slick interface for quickly jotting down a bunch of tags without having to repeatedly press form buttons.

I've seen this interface in Mail.app and a few other places in OSX, so that makes me wonder if there's some sort of cocoa class out there for this. Anyone know of one? If not, I guess I'm looking at a custom opengl view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `NSTokenFieldCell`.

Comment: Or NSTokenField for the stand-alone (not hosted in a table view or matrix) version.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks guys! I'm brushing up on tokens through this guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555